# ISO 15693 Read multiple blocks returns Tag response error=2

Tags: swift, nfc, iso-15693

I'm trying to read multiple blocks from ISO-15693 NFC tag, whenever I start to read it I get this error

> Error Domain=NFCError Code=102 "Tag response error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Tag response error, ISO15693TagResponseErrorCode=2}

This is how I try to read it

```
 tagHandler(NFCISO15693Tag.self, arguments, result) { tag in
       let requestFlags = getRequestFlags(arguments["requestFlags"] as! [String])
      let blockNumber = arguments["blockNumber"] as! Int
      let numberOfBlocks = arguments["numberOfBlocks"] as! Int
        tag.readMultipleBlocks(requestFlags: requestFlags, blockRange: NSMakeRange(blockNumber, numberOfBlocks)) { dataBlocks, error in
        if let error = error {
          result(getFlutterError(error))
        } else {
          result(dataBlocks)
        }
      }
    }
```

However I managed to read single block by changing request flags to [.highDataRate], but this change won't help on readMultipleblocks command

```
 tagHandler(NFCISO15693Tag.self, arguments, result) { tag in
     let requestFlags = getRequestFlags(arguments["requestFlags"] as! [String])
     let blockNumber = arguments["blockNumber"] as! UInt8

     tag.readSingleBlock(requestFlags: [.highDataRate], blockNumber: blockNumber) { dataBlock, error in
       if let error = error {
         result(getFlutterError(error))
       } else {
         result(dataBlock)
       }
     }
   }
```

I couldn't find many examples or resources about reading multiple blocks from ISO-15693 tag, so any information or an example would help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find a workaround by using readSingle block with async threading. It takes about 0.6sec to read 50 blocks. I'm not familiar with swift language so I bet this could be optimised better.

```
  @available(iOS 13.0, *)
  private func handleIso15693ReadSingleBlock(_ arguments: [String : Any?], result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    tagHandler(NFCISO15693Tag.self, arguments, result) { tag in
        let accessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "NFCManager.accessQueue")
        let blockCount = arguments["blockNumber"] as! UInt8

        var dataBlocks = [Data]()
        let group = DispatchGroup()

        group.enter();
        
        for i in 3...blockCount{
            accessQueue.async {
                tag.readSingleBlock(requestFlags: [.highDataRate], blockNumber: UInt8(i)) { dataBlock, error in
                  if let error = error {
                    result(getFlutterError(error))
                  } else {
                    dataBlocks.append(dataBlock)
                    if (i == blockCount){
                        group.leave();
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        group.wait()

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
               result(dataBlocks)
           }
    }
  }
```